# After cloning a git repo, Xcode says it can't contact the server when I try to update

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, bitbucket-server

I created a git branch called bugfix/development and cloned the branch and opened the project in Xcode 5. After making some modifications, I tried to Commit my changes and Xcode said it could't access the repository.

When looking at Xcode preferences, the repository was online in the Accounts area.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The "/" in the branch name was causing problems with the Xcode/git integration. After renaming the branch from bugfix/development to development, the Xcode/git integration worked great.

Here is how I changed the branch name:

```
$ git branch development origin/bugfix/development
$ git push origin development
$ git push origin :bug fix/development
```

Then,
    $ git fetch origin
    $ git remote prune origin

and now I can see the new branch. All users would need to perform the last two commands in order to see the change.